What is taking PySpark so much time in this loop?
I am requesting an Api (limited to 30calls per min so I do not parallelize) in a PySpark notebook (azure synapse analytics), and it takes ages in the synapse notebook while it's lightning fast on my local env (PY3 kernel - jupyter notebook).
Being quite new to PySpark, I wonder which operation(s) is taking so much time.
# Request functions
# First function
def get_response(url):
   headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {INSEE_KEY}'}
   response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   return response

#Second function using the first one
def get_data_by_siret(siret):
   siret_url = f'{base_url}siret?q=siret:{siret}'
   response = get_response(siret_url)
   if response.status_code == 200 :
     content = response.json()
     siret_data = content['etablissements']
     print(f'Siret: {siret} collecté. (timestamp: {time.time()})')
     return siret_data, 200
   elif response.status_code == 429:
     print(f'Siret: {siret} ; quota atteint. (timestamp: {time.time()})')
     return [], 429
   elif response.status_code == 404:
     print(f'Siret {siret} inconnu dans la base Sirene')
     return [], 404
   else : 
     print(f'Siret {siret}. {response.status_code}, (timestamp: {time.time()})')
     return [], response.status_code

Here is the very slow part.
# Collecting Sirets data
sirets_json = []
timestamps = []
siret_429 = []

for siret in array_siret:
   time.sleep(1)
   siret_data, status = get_data_by_siret(siret)
   timestamps.append(time.time())
   if status == 200:
     sirets_json.extend(siret_data)
   elif status == 429:
     time.sleep(1)
     siret_429.append(siret)

By 'very slow' I mean this:
Siret: 04555025800029 collected. (timestamp: 1720795818.7682683) 'Fri Jul 12 14:50:18 2024'
Siret: 05780615000017 collected. (timestamp: 1720795851.364306) 'Fri Jul 12 14:50:51 2024'
Siret: 09572031400475 collected. (timestamp: 1720795883.9143667) 'Fri Jul 12 14:51:23 2024'

On my local env, with the exact same code, I can collect 60 sirets in ~75 seconds.

Did you check how long it takes each time to connect to the API and get a response?

Indeed, simply calling 5 different urls with a 'for url in urls: get_response(url)' takes a lot of time: 15:40:48 to 15:42:54. I don't understand why. Maybe a network issue/bottleneck in the spark pool.

Is it a standard behaviour for azure sparkpools to be quite slow in communicating through http requests? My spkpool is located in France, like my synapse env, and also like the API endpoint I'm sending requests to (therefore the travel shouldn't be that long).
